# Split on String in C#

Tags: c#, split

I have a Java program I am re-writing in C#.

I'm trying to split a string on another string so in Java it's

```
String raw = strLine.split(" : ")
```

How can I do the same in C#? As far as I can tell, the `.Split` function only allows for chars, not Strings. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: `string[] raw = strLine.split(':')`

Comment: He wants to split on white spaces too.

Comment: @JoelLegaspiEnriquez notice the spaces before and after the ':' ? That's the whole problem...

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var raw = text.Split(new[] {" : "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code can help:

```
string s = text.Split(new string[] { " : " },StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] raw = strLine.Split(new char[] { ' ', ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this too in C#

string[] raw = Regex.Split(strLine, ":");

Click [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-split) to check it